# Hide Button Once All Divs are Visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="persons">
    <div class="per1"></div>
    <div class="per2"></div>
    <div class="per3"></div>
    <div class="per4"></div>
    <div class="per5"></div>
    <div class="per6"></div>
    <div class="per7"></div>
    <div class="per8"></div>
    <div class="per9"></div>
    <div class="per10"></div>
</div>

<a id="add-person" href="#" class="button brand">Add Person Involved</a>
```

All but the first div (`per1`) are hidden by default.

Then with the following JS I can show the next div if a person clicks the button.

```
$("#add-person").click(function(){
    if ($(".persons div:visible").next().length != 0){
        $(".persons div:visible").next().slideDown('slow');
    }
    return false;
});
```

This works but my issue is once the 10th div becomes visible I want the `Add Person Involved` button to be hidden.

I tried adding the following code to the above click function but it doesn't work:

```
if ( $(".persons div:visible").length === 10){
    $("#add-person").hide();
}
```

How do I hide the button once the 10th div (aka `class="per10"`) becomes visible?

Comment: Where you have this condition to hide? it would be in $("#add-person").click event handler

Comment: The issue is that `length === 10` will not happen, since the count starts at 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check for :hidden after visible the div

```
if ( $(".persons div:hidden").length == 0){
    $("#add-person").hide();
}
```

and you can try to use `:last()` visible and check for `is("hidden")` for the next div

```
$("#add-person").click(function(){
    if ($(".persons div:visible:last").next().is(':hidden')){
        $(".persons div:visible:last").next().slideDown('slow' , function(){
            if ( $(".persons div:hidden").length == 0){
                $("#add-person").hide();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/jrrg1sgb/3/)

and instead of using in css

```
.per2, .per3, .per4, .per5, .per6, .per7, .per8, .per9, .per10{
  display:none;
}
```

you can use

```
.persons > div{
    display : none;
}
```

or

```
.persons > div[class^="per"]{  // this mean div with class starts with per
     display : none;
}
```

Comment: @Lynda updated answer  .. sorry my bad   :visible:last  not :last:visible :)